# Why do singular values decay as O(1/k) for this triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a $d\times d$ matrix with $k$'th row consisting of $k$ constants $\underbrace{c, c,\ldots,c}_{k}$ and the rest 0. Rows are normalized to have norm 1. Can we say anything about singular values of this matrix?

IE, for $d=5$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Empirically, it appears that norm $\approx \sqrt{d}$ and the rest of the singular values decay approximately as $O(1/k)$ for large $d$. Meanwhile $k$th eigenvalues is exactly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.
Is there an easy way to explain this?

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-triangular-singularvalues.nb)

Comment: By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2847662) we at least have $\text{norm} \leq \sqrt{d}$.