# When is the spectral norm of a matrix less than 1?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with non-negative entries.
What are some sufficient conditions that allow me to conclude $\left\|A\right\|_2 < 1 $?

I am interested in stochastic and sub-stochastic matrices in particular.

Comment: The induced $2$-norm of every stochastic matrix is $\ge1$. It is equal to $1$ if and only if the matrix is doubly stochastic.

Comment: And what about sub-stochastic matrices, i.e. , there is at least a row that sums up to a number that is strictly less than 1 ?

Comment: I am not aware of any nice sufficient conditions for sub-stochastic matrices. Of course, if the matrix is strictly sub-stochastic and normal, its norm will be smaller than $1$, but very few sub-stochastic matrices are normal, so this condition is not useful.

Comment: One probably more useful sufficient condition is that one of $A$ and $A^T$ is sub-stochastic and the other is strictly sub-stochastic. In this case, $\|A\|_2^2\le\|A\|_1\|A\|_\infty<1$.

Comment: @user1551 Regarding your first comment: I can see that "if" holds by Birkhoff-von Neumann. Is there a quick way to see why "only if" applies?

Comment: @BenGrossmann See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1129977) of mine.

Comment: @user1551 Wonderful proof, thanks for sharing